# .../node_modules/graphql/error/sytnaxError.js `return new _GraphQLError.GraphQLError(`

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am starting a Apollo/GraphQL backend to a Reactjs Project. I'm still in the early phases (and relatively new to this kind of backend work so please bare with me) and just trying to get everything to a state where I can successfully run `node server.js` and get the backend spinning. I have been running it, getting an error and fixing it for quite a few rotations now, but I am now getting an error that provides essentially no help on where to look or what exactly I'm looking for. Upon running `node server.js` I get this response...

```
/Users/nickfatherbool/code/personal/finance/value_tracker/backend/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:15
  return new _GraphQLError.GraphQLError(


    GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
    at syntaxError (/Users/nickfatherbool/code/personal/finance/value_tracker/backend/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:15:10)
```

I tried using `Ctrl + F` to find the line `return new _GraphQLError.GraphQLError(` but I was unable to find anything like that. I'm pretty sure that digging through the `node-modules` directory would be a waste of time since seldom is that ever the answer, plus I tried deleting the directory and running `npm i` again, so I doubt there's anything I could fix in there anyway. Currently, my `server.js` file is constructed as so...

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import typeDefs from './graphql/typeDefs.js';
import resolvers from './graphql/resolvers/index.js';
import util from 'util'


dotenv.config();

const startApolloServer = async () => {
    const app = express()
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        context: ({req}) => ({req})
    })

    const whitelist = [
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "http://localhost:4000/graphql",        
        "https://studio.apollographql.com",
    ]

    app.use(cors({ /* credentials: true, */ origin: "*" })); 
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Welcome to SQL');
    });

    await server.start()
    await server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql', cors: false });
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${process.env.PORT}... GraphQL/Apollo at studio.apollographql.com/dev`));
}

startApolloServer()
```

And I have my `prisma.schema` and `typeDefs.js` files all properly set up... I could attach them if needed but I'm pretty sure they're unrelated to the issue at hand. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong, or any advice on where I should look for the answer?

These are the only mutations/queries that have been made thus far...

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import generateToken from '../../utils/generateToken.js';
import { UserInputError } from 'apollo-server-errors';
import checkGlobalAuth from '../../utils/checkAuthorization/checkGlobalAuth.js';
import db from '../../utils/generatePrisma.js';
import hashPassword from '../../utils/passwordHasher.js';
import { validateRegisterInput } from '../../utils/validators.js';
import { checkExistingUserByEmail, checkExistingUserByPhone } from '../../utils/checkExisting.js';


export default {
    Query: {
        getUser: async (_, { }, context) => {
            const user = await checkGlobalAuth(context)

            try {
                return await db.user.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        id: user.id
                    },
                    include: {
                        stocks: true
                    }
                })
            } catch(error){
                throw new Error(error)
            }
        }
    },
    Mutation: {

        user_signUp: async (_, { fullname, email, password, phoneNumber } ) => {
            try {

                // This creates TWO consts -- valid AND errors based off of validateRegisterInput's returns. Look at 
                // utils/validators to see what ther validateRegisterInput does    
                const {
                    valid,   // True or False
                    errors   // Object that has subobjects for potential email / password / fullname errors
                } = validateRegisterInput(
                    email,
                    password,
                    fullname
                );

                // Makes the email in all caps for storage/comparison reasons
                email = await email.toUppeCase()
                // Checks to make sure all inputs were properly filled
                if (!valid) {
                    throw new userInputError('Errors', {
                        errors
                    });
                }

                // Imported function. Checks duplicate enails
                let existingUser =  await checkExistingUserByEmail(email)
                if (existingUser) {
                    throw new UserInputError('email is taken', {
                        errors: {
                            email: 'Email is already taken!',
                        },
                    });
                }

                // Import function. Checks duplicate phoneNumbers
                existingUser = await checkExistingUserByPhone(phoneNumber)
                if (existingUser) {
                    throw new UserInputError('email is taken', {
                        errors: {
                            phoneNumber: 'Phone Number is already in use!',
                        },
                    });
                }

                // Imported function. Hashes password
                password = await hashPassword(password)

                // Creates a User Account
                let user =  await db.user.create({
                    data: {
                        name: fullname,
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
                    }
                })

                // Imported function. Generates session token
                token = await generateToken(user.id)


                // Returns the created User with a session token
                return {...user, token: token}


            } catch(error){ 
                console.loig(error)
                throw new Error(error)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The only other files I have in play are my `typeDefs` and `prisma.schema` files, which respectively look as so...

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

const typeDefs = gql`
    scalar Date
    scalar JSON

    type User{
        id:                 ID
        username:           String  
        password:           String
        email:              String
        TD_userName:        String  
        TD_password:        String
        stocks:             [Stock]
        emailList:          [JSON]
        buySellList:        [JSON]
        tradeHistory:       [JSON]
    }

    type Stock{
        id:                 ID
        name:               String
        ticker:             String
        lastValue:          JSON
        valueHistory:       JSON
        growthExpected:     Int 
        growthSoFar:        Int 
        growthRatio:        Int
        users:              [User]
        link:               String
    }

    
    type Query {

    }

    type Mutation {

    }



`
export default typeDefs
```

And this is the `prisma.schema`

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  // BASIC INFORMATION
  id            Int             @id@default(autoincrement())
  username      String          @unique
  passsword     String          
  email         String
  phoneNumber   String          @unique

  // BANKING INFORMATION
  TD_userName   String          @unique
  TD_password   String

  // FUNCTIONAL INFORMATION
  emailList     Json[]
  buySellList   Json[]
  tradeHistory  Json[]

  // CONNECTIONS
  stocks        Stock[]
}

model Stock {
  // BASIC INFORMATION
  id              Int             @id@default(autoincrement())
  name            String          @unique
  ticker          String          @unique

  // STATISTICAL AND HISTORICAL DATA
  lastValue       Json
  valueHistory    Json[]
  growthExpected  Int
  growthSoFar     Int
  growthRatio     Int

  // CONNECTIONS
  users           User[]
  link            String
}
```

Comment: It tells you there is a syntax error in your GraphQL query: `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".` - You should check the query you are sending from your frontend (you didn't show it in your question).

Comment: No frontend at all currently, and I only have one mutation and one query even created yet. Would this be an issue with a resolver?

Comment: Can you include the query in your question please? It sounds like there is the syntax error.

Comment: Got it, added it now

Comment: There is no GraphQL in the code you posted (but you have some typos: `toUppeCase`, `console.loig`) - I bet the error is in `typeDefs.js` or the schema file then... It has to be where there is some actual GraphQL "code".

Comment: Perfect, I found it. It was because I didn't fill in any values for Mutation / Query types in the typeDefs. Thank you! @CherryDT

Answer (score 0):

This did just end up being a stupid sytnax error. I needed to have `type Mutation { ... }` and `type Query{ ... }`inside of the `typeDef` file or else I would get some error letting me know `Query` and `Mutation` were defined in the Resolvers but not the schema. Adding those types fixed that error, but since they were empty objects THAT through the syntax error in question.